# How to lists all users who logged in on a specific day using grep and last

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, grep, last

I need to write a command or sequence of commands that lists all users who logged in on a monday by using last and grep. I came up with this but it didnt work:

> grep -i /var/log/wtmp | last -t 20150731

Answer (score 1):

`last | grep -i Mon` (although the `-i` option shouldn't be needed if you capitalize "Mon" as I have it)

Your proposed solution has a few problems:

- The pipe `|` symbol sends (pipes) the standard output of the first program (on the left) to the second program (as standard input). So what you're doing is trying to pipe the output of `grep -i /var/log/wtmp` to `last -t 20150731`. Since `last` outputs the login info, it needs to come first.
- `grep -i /var/log/wtmp` tries to find "/var/log/wtmp" in standard input (case insensitive). It is possible to have `grep` search a file, but the file comes after whatever you're searching for (e.g., `grep find_me in_this_file` searches the file `in_this_file` for the string "find_me"). Since no file is specified, it looks in standard input. With `last` first (before the pipe), that's the output of `last`; but with `grep` first, that's whatever you type after you hit Enter to execute the command.
- In this case, you actually need to use `grep` to search for "Mon", not "/var/log/wtmp". `last` uses "/var/log/wtmp", but all `grep` cares about is the output of `last`, not where `last` gets its data from.
- `last -t 20150731` would output all logins up to (but not including) July 31, 2015. (To include July 31, you'd need to specify August 1 as the date.) Only problem is that `last` requires hyphens in the date *unless* you specify the full time (including seconds). So you need hyphens in `last -t 2015-07-31` but not in `last -t 20150731000000` (both of which specify the same time, midnight *beginning* July 31, 2015). Your initial question doesn't specify a need to limit the list by date, so I've left it out of my answer above; if you do need to limit by date, use `last -t 2015-07-31` to list through July 30 (not including July 31) or `last -t 2015-08-01` through July 31.

For more details (including all the fun stuff `grep` can do with regular expressions and the different time formats for `last`), try checking the man pages with `man grep` and `man last`.

The above displays logins in reverse chronological order (most recent first). Although it goes beyond the constraints of your original question by adding another command, you can also display the results in chronological order (most recent last) by piping the results of `grep` to the `tac` command: `last | grep -i Mon | tac`.

Answer (score 0):

```
last | grep Mon | awk '{print $1}' | sort -u
```

Comment: No point piping `grep` to `awk`: `last | awk '/Mon/ {print $1}'`...